# What to conclude from $x y \le N$ and $x\le 1$?

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

For real $x, y, N$, what can we conclude for $y$ from two inequalities:

$$x y \le N\qquad {\rm and} \qquad x\le 1?$$

Comment: Nothing, in general. If $x=0$ then you have no information on $y$.

Comment: And for $x\ne 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \ne 0$. Then you have six cases following from $x y \le N$:

1. For $0 < x \le 1$ and $N \ge 0$ you have $0  \le y \le \frac{N}{x}$ .
2. For $0 < x \le 1$ and $N < 0$ you have $  y \le \frac{N}{x} < N < 0 $ .
3. For $-1 \le x <0$ and $N \ge 0$ you have $0  \ge y \ge \frac{N}{x}$ .
4. For $-1 \le x <0$ and $N < 0$ you have $0 \le -N  \le \frac{N}{x} \le y$ .
5. For $x < -1 $ and $N \ge 0$ you have $0 \ge y \ge\frac{N}{x} > -N$ .
6. For $x < -1 $ and $N < 0$ you have $  y \ge  \frac{N}{x}  \ge 0$ .